# Как сделать чтобы никнейм не вылезал за рамки блока?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<section>
    <a @click="exit" class="exxxit">Exit</a>
    <p class="vhod">Вы вошли как <strong>{{ otvet }}</strong></p>
</section>
```

```
.vhod{
display:inline-block;
padding-left:850px;
margin-right: auto
}
.exxxit{
color: black;
display:inline-block
}
.exxxit:hover {
color:crimson; 
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Как сделать чтобы никнейм не вылезал за рамки блока?

Comment: Картинку я так понимаю добавили недавно, вам нужно поместить секцию в блок который определяет ширину контента.

Comment: изменил ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял то, возможно так:

```css
.vhod{
  float: right;
}
  .exxxit{
color: black;
}
  .exxxit:hover {
color:crimson; 
text-decoration: underline;
}

section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.content{
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <a @click="exit" class="exxxit">Exit</a>
        <span class="vhod">Вы вошли как <strong>{{ otvet }}</strong></span>
        <div class="content">
            <!--например контентная часть-->
        </div>
    </section>
```

тег `<p>` - параграф, он и переходит на след строку. мб с тегом `<span>` вам будет проще манипулировать текстом?

Answer (score 0):

Верстайте при помощи [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) и в целом почитайте про вёрстку.

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.vhod {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.exxxit {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block
}

.exxxit:hover {
  color: crimson;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="top">
    <a @click="exit" class="exxxit">Exit</a>
    <p class="vhod">Вы вошли как <strong>{{ otvet }}</strong></p>
  </div>
</section>
```